# Toolchains for ARM

Tags: linux, eclipse-plugin, arm, stm32

What's different between the  "GNU  MCU Eclipse ARM 
 Embedded GCC "  and "GNU ARM Embedded toolchain"? I'm new in Linux world and I need to programming STM32F4DISCOVERY board.  And I can't understand what toolchain need is .

Comment: Install open Stm32 or Attolic Stm32 studio. Both are eclipse based and both install and configure the tool chain the correct ay. As you do not have any experience,, do not even try to create the DIY way as you will 100% fail. When you get more experience you can start to tune the tool chain to your liking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at this article if you're curious about getting started with toolchains. It's from Nordic, not ST Micro, but it's very helpful to understand how the toolchain, makefile, and IDE all work together.

https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/tutorials/b/getting-started/posts/development-with-gcc-and-eclipse

I believe the brief answer to your question is that:

- GNU MCU Eclipse ARM Embedded GCC is a family of extensions to the Eclipse IDE to develop code for ARM devices
- GNU ARM Embedded toolchain is from ARM, and it's purely the compiler, linker, etc. needed to make a command line call to compile a C file and generate a binary for an ARM processor

If you're just looking to crank something out on your STM32, I would look to see if they have an IDE for your board/ application, as they're usually pre-bundled with the toolchain and an SDK.

Comment: **GNU MCU Eclipse** is the "family of extensions", **GNU MCU Eclipse ARM Embedded GCC** is the "compiler, linker, etc." part of that family.

Answer (score 0):

`GNU MCU Eclipse ARM Embedded GCC` is based on the `GNU ARM Embedded toolchain`. From the [README](https://github.com/gnu-mcu-eclipse/arm-none-eabi-gcc-build/blob/master/README-out.md):

> Compared to the ARM distribution, the build procedure is more or less the same and there should be no functional differences.
>
> The only addition affects newlib, which was extended with `printf()`/`scanf()` support for `long long` and C99 formats (`--enable-newlib-io-long-long` and `--enable-newlib-io-c99-formats`).

The Docker images used to create the `GNU MCU Eclipse ARM Embedded GCC` release are also available on the project page, should you ever need it (probably not).

You should be fine with either of them installed along with the rest of the `GNU MCU Eclipse` suite.

Comment: I tried C99 format %hhu but it doesn't work. I just get "hu" string instead of a number. Of course %u works. The _WANT_IO_C99_FORMATS macro is defined in the newlib. Toolchain release 8.2.1-1.7-20190524-0603.

Comment: @grzegorz why don't you ask it as a new question? Perhaps with some more details.